# Highlight a Calendar date on a Text Date Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I was wondering if it would be possible to show a date selected for example on a jquery date picker if a user hovers over a texted based date.

I have a list of dates in spans

```
<span>8-21-2014</span>
<span>9-1-2014</span>
<span>10-2-2014</span>
```

The goal would be the datepicker (or any other method of showing a calendar ie:keithwood ) would be off to the side and would highlight / change month when the span is hovered giving the user a visual idea of where that date lands in the month.

**Note:** I already have a calendar page, the list based view just gets more views.

Comment: As you may know the jQuery UI datepicker does not support this functionality. You could still write your own functions. Using the UI Datepicker you would have to trigger the click events (for changing month and date) when you span is hovered. However, this would be a really dirty way to do it.

Comment: Yea I assumed it wouldn't have something like that, plus I felt the picker would slow down the page. Trying to also think of a light weight calendar.